# Issues with Wacom tablet, possible bug

Tags: system-settings, wacom

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. I have a Wacom Intuos pen input which was working perfectly fine before the upgrade, but the wacom driver is now buggy to the point of unuseable (specifics below), does anyone have any suggestions on how to manually control screen mapping? I have 3 monitors: two horizontal, and one rotated to be vertical.  When I setup my wacom tablet before, I had it set to be mapped to a single monitor.

- First question, there used to be something in the settings to map the top buttons to actions (in particular, I liked setting one button to switch between screens for the mapping), but that doesn't appear to be included anymore, will that come back?

  - Second main question, there is something massively wrong with the automatic single monitor mapping right now.  For both of my regular screens, the mapping only uses the left half of my wacom tablet. It registers the right half, but the entire right half gets mapped to the right edge of the screen.
  - For the vertical monitor, it maps the tablet rotated, and again, only seems to work with the left side of the wacom tablet.

Hints or suggestions to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Now that I pandemic-live online, I really need to get this back up and running!

Answer (score 3):

After some back and forth on [a linuxwacom bug report](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/issues/118), the solution is that there is a problem with the wacom tablet sometimes [mislabeling linux as android](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Known-Issues#android-misdetect). The solution is to hold down the left most and right most buttons for 3-4 seconds until the light turns off and on again.  This switches the tablet from android to PC mode and fixed my issue.

Comment: Thank you!! I was going crazy because of the android mode. Just pressing the 2 keys for some seconds changed the mode to PC, that solved the issue. Single laptop screen on Fedora 33.
Horizontal lines were larger than vertical ones. I draw a square on the tablet and it painted a rectangle.