# Calibrating Bosto16HD with Wacom Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, wacom, graphics-tablet

I have a Bosto16HD graphics tablet and I've been trying to get it to work on Ubuntu 20.04 with Cinnamon environment. After some fiddling around with wacom drivers, I got it to work, but the stylus only "recognizes" half the screen horizontally.

Most of the fixes for actual wacom devices involves holding two buttons until the screen turns off and on, [entering PC mode instead of Android mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235795/issues-with-wacom-tablet-possible-bug). However, although this tablet has physical buttons, they don't get properly mapped, I've checked with evtest and they simply give nothing.

I've tried a variety of xsetwacom MapToOutput values, [as per this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286571/wacom-intuous-tablet-not-mapping-to-single-monitor), but nothing worked. These are my xrander results:

```
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 575mm x 323mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    23.98    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-4 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080    120.01*+  60.00
```

I tried both `xinput map-to-output 11 HDMI-0` and DP-4 (11 being the id for the stylus), but it changed nothing, it still thought the middle of the screen was the right edge. I have also tried setting the mode to absolute and relative. Absolute works fine, but relative gives an error:

```
~$ xsetwacom set "BYX Tablet Device pad" mode "relative"
X Error of failed request:  XI_BadMode (invalid Mode parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_SetDeviceMode)
  Mode id in failed request: 0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  16
```

Using the Graphics Tablet tool to calibrate didn't work. It didn't matter if I used the screen mirrored or as a separate screen. My laptop has a nvidia graphics card and i'm currently using nvidia-driver-460

On lsusb, it shows up as `ID 0ed1:7821 WinMaxGroup Tablet Device`. I don't know why on xinput it shows up as BYX Tablet Device. This is how I've set it on the 50-digimend.conf file

```
#/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-digimend.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Bosto 16HD with Wacom Driver"
        MatchUSBID "0ed1:7821"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

Right now, I'm out of ideas. Is it possible to emulate the keypresses of the wacom tablet so as to force that PC mode restart? What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to properly map screen for Bosto16HD:

```
xsetwacom set Area 100 90 17920 10240
```